# Ajax Post arrays null in controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I always get null arrays when I send them by AJAX to controller which looks like that:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public decimal CountAdditionalSellPrice(PaintballItemQuantity[] piq_tab, EventOtherOption[] eoo_tab, int VAT = 8)
 {
   ...
 }
```

I use this script on my HTML page:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function countAdditionalSell()
    {
        var primary = [];
        var primary2 = [];
        var primary_el = {};

        $("#primaryAdditionalSell").find($('.form-group').find('input')).each(function () {
            primary.push(primary_el[this.name] = this.value);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < primary.length; i = i + 3) {
            var x = {
                ID: primary[i],
                Name: primary[i + 1],
                Quantity: primary[i + 2]
            };
            primary2.push(x);
        }

        var additional = [];
        var additional2 = [];
        var additional_el = {};

        $("#otherAdditionalSell").find($('.form-group').find('input')).each(function () {
            additional.push(additional_el[this.name] = this.value);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < additional.length - 1; i = i + 6) {
            var x = {
                ID: additional[i],
                EventID: additional[i + 1],
                Name: additional[i + 2],
                Price: additional[i + 3],
                Quantity: additional[i + 4]
            };
            additional2.push(x);
        }

        console.log(primary2);
        console.log(additional2);
        var vat = 8;
        if ($('#Event_PaymentType').val() == 1)
        {
            var vat = $('input[type=radio]:checked', '#vatButtons').val();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            url: "/EventNotes/CountAdditionalSellPrice",
            data: { piq_tab: primary2, eoo_tab: additional2, VAT: vat },
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#Note_AdditionalSellsCost").val(data);
            }
        });
        countWorkerMoney();
    };
</script>
```

And e.g. in `primary2` I have:

```
0:{ID: "8", Name: "7 Up 1L", Quantity: "0"}
1:{ID: "21", Name: "7 Up 2L", Quantity: "0"}
2:{ID: "25", Name: "CocaCola 1L", Quantity: "0"}
3:{ID: "22", Name: "CocaCola 2L", Quantity: "0"}
```

Example `additional2` objects in array:

```
0: {ID: "9", EventID: "676", Name: "ExampleName", Price: "1,00", Quantity: "1"}
```

My ViewModels:

```
public class PaintballItemQuantity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

public class EventOtherOption
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> ItemID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nazwa")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nazwa jest wymagana", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cena")]
        [Range(0.01, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Cena nie może być mniejsza niż 0.01!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ilość")]
        [DefaultValue(1)]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Ilość nie może być mniejsza niż 0!")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller parameters are always null, but what's strange I'm using same script (only part with getting VAT value is changed) on another view and it works perfect (having same primary2 values as above). Can someone tell me what is wrong here or why I'm having null values recieved from one view but on the other I have my controller parameters filled with values like above?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide us the source code of ...

- the Viewmodels.
- the second controller method definition/header.
- the second script where the VAT part is different.

**Update 1 - Approach 1**

First of all you are declaring the variable vat two times in your script. Only assign the value to vat in the true part of your if statement. In the working script you are getting the vat value from the ViewBag. Let me guess that the return type is a string. In the not working script you assign an integer value to the variable vat. Json data needs to be stringified!

Try to replace this code

```
var vat = 8;
if ($('#Event_PaymentType').val() == 1)
{
    var vat = $('input[type=radio]:checked', '#vatButtons').val();
}
```

with this

```
var vat = "8";
if ($('#Event_PaymentType').val() === "1")
{
    vat = $('input[type=radio]:checked', '#vatButtons').val();
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wGHA35E3 - ViewModels
There is no second method, I want to use same controller function by those two scripts
https://pastebin.com/EvYijB2d - second script, example `additional2` object in array: `0: {ID: "9", EventID: "676", Name: "ExampleName", Price: "1,00", Quantity: "1"}`

Comment: No, I just checked it and it doesn't work anyway. I even deleted second and third parameter from script and controller, so I only pass `primary2` array and it is still null in controller which has only one parameter as `PaintballItemQuantity[] piq_tab`

Answer (score 0):

put your three parameters in a class and replace parameters with one parameter

Comment: It is still null, if I use `data: JSON.stringify(toSend)` then I have the model, but arrays inside this model are null and VAT is 0

Comment: after put one parameter on action you must set content-type header of ajax 'application/json'

Comment: I tried many options, none of them worked. I wrote a script which will do same thing as I wanted to do on server-side. Thanks for trying.